# ¿Como puedo enviar un valor null (nulo) a un campo LONGBLOB en SQL?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, webservice, blob

**Descripción:**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio, la cual está conectada a una base de datos SQL por medio de Web Services escritos en lenguaje PHP.

La base de datos tiene una tabla llamada *"sugerencias"*, la cual contiene 3 campos distintos (*id_usuario, sugerencia, imagen*).

En mi aplicación tengo un *Edit Text* el cual va a recibir las sugerencias de los usuarios. Luego hay una *Image View* la cual va a recibir una imágen seleccionada por el usuario.

El usuario está obligado a escribir una sugerencia, pero no está obligado a enviar una imágen.

**Resumen:**

1- El usuario puede enviar a la base de datos un texto (campo sugerencia) junto a una imágen (campo imagen).

2- El usuario puede enviar a la base de datos un texto (campo sugerencia) pero no una imágen (por lo que el campo "imagen" de la base de datos no debería tener una imágen, sino un valor nulo o, en su defecto, el campo quedaría vacío.

**¿Que necesito?**

Quiero saber que tengo que hacer para que el campo imagen (de tipo longblob) pueda quedar vacío o tener un valor nulo.

**Adjunto el código PHP de mi Web Service**

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost="localhost";
$database_localhost="bd_prueba";
$username_localhost="root";
$password_localhost="hola";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

$id_usuario = $_POST["id_usuario"];
$sugerencia = $_POST["sugerencia"];
$imagen = $_POST["imagen"];

$ruta = "imagenes/$id_usuario.jpg";

file_put_contents($ruta,base64_decode($imagen));
$bytesArchivo=file_get_contents($ruta);

$sql="INSERT INTO sugerencias VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stm=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$stm->bind_param('iss',$id_usuario,$sugerencia,$bytesArchivo);
    
if($stm->execute()){
    echo "registra";
}else{
    echo "noRegistra";
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

**Dato importante:**

El código de mi web service que acaban de ver, solamente funciona si el usuario introduce texto e imagen.

Si el usuario decide no cargar una imagen, el servicio no va a funcionar. Es por esto que me gustaría que me ayuden indicándome que debería hacer para poder pasarle un valor nulo al campo "imagen".

**Muchas gracias por leer.**

Comment: Será que desde la base debes de definir como NOT NULL el campo longblob, otra seria, validar si viene vacio la imagen insertar un null en el campo

Comment: Hola @DonaldoManzano y muchas gracias por responder. Jamás se me cruzó por la cabeza pensar en eso. De hecho, hasta recién, nunca me pregunté para que servía ese campo de not null. Lo voy a probar :)

Comment: @DonaldoManzano acabo de hacer la prueba y, efectivamente, mi campo imagen no permitía los null. Ahora lo cambié pero aún así no funciona :(

Comment: Recibes algún error? Desde php

Comment: @DonaldoManzano me conecto a mis web services desde mi app por medio de la librería volley. El error se da en Response.ErrorListener porque no se logra conectar con el web service (esto cuando intento pasarle valores nulos).